# Strange behavior of the htaccess redirection with www and slash

Tags: html, .htaccess

I make an analyse of the site and was faced with a problem in htaccess redirection. It is a strange, I did it many times before and had never the problem like this.
So, I try to just redirect my domen to without www and shash:

```
 ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    rewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domen.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And also I remove the slash at the end of url

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

And after this I make a redirect from non-existing or unused page to 404 error:

```
RedirectMatch 404 ^/non-existing-page$ or ^/non-existing-page/$
```

When I type in the browser `http://www.domen.com/non-existing-page` (with www) or `http:domen.com/non-existing-page` (with slash) a have the same url with 404 error code and 404 html code. It's all right.

But if I write the url `http://www.domen.com/non-existing-pag/` (with www and shash) I'm redirected to `404.html` page with the 200 - no error code.

What's wrong?

At the start of .htaccess I have only

```
<IfModule mod_speling.c>
CheckSpelling on
</IfModule>
```

That's all.

Comment: _“And also I remove the slash at the end of url”_ - how so? The RewriteRule you have shown here doesn’t treat a slash differently, or even looks for one. You are just matching _everything_ there, the full request path - and then you redirect to the _same, full match_ ...

Comment: Now I left only this rules and I have the same result with www...
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

RedirectMatch 404 ^/non-exists-page$

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domen.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: and sorry, I fixed the rule for slash

Comment: Why are you _redirecting_ to the 404 page to begin with? `ErrorDocument` should already take care of serving that script if a non-existing resource is requested.

Comment: I just wanted to present some of existing pages as a non-existing without redirecting to main

Comment: Why not just delete or rename those pages then? In any case, that should not be done using Redirect(Match), because that will cause an _external_ direct - so the information that the _originally_ requested URL caused a 404 is lost (f.e. to search engines)

Comment: Yes I can delete this page, I was searching the fastest way and also I have a blog into the inside directory domen.com/blog/non-existing and I wanted to make the same error page for both the site and blog through redirect.
Now I understand that is not possible through this method, maybe you know how can I do it?

Comment: I've just copied my page to blog. Thank's anyway.